# How to add a package-info.class to a ShrinkWrap archive?

Tags: shrinkwrap

I have a `packge-info.java` file in one of my packages. It contains some package wide used annotations.

How can I add the corresponding `package-info.class` to a ShrinkWrap archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the following solution:

```java
  archive.addPackages(false, new Filter<ArchivePath>()
  {
     @Override
     public boolean include(ArchivePath path)
     {
         return path.get().endsWith("package-info.class");
     }
  }, SDMEventBroadcaster.class.getPackage());
```

It does what I expect but it would be nice to have a solution without a filter.